# Show preview of Image and upload file with AngularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, file-upload, angularjs-directive

I want upload file/image with input type="file" of HTML5 using AngularJs and when the user upload the image show the preview. So I created my custom directive in this way:

```
var modulo = angular.module('myApp', []);

modulo.directive('fileModel', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AEC',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('change', function (event) {
                //Take the object
                var fetchFile = event.target.files[0];
                //emit the object upward
                scope.$emit('fileSelected', fetchFile);
            });            
        }
    };
});
```

Now I show my controller when I take the object (file/image) and with this controller I want show the preview.

```
modulo.controller('myController', function ($scope, $http) {

    var files;

    $scope.$on('fileSelected', function(event, fetchFile) {
        //Receive the object from another scope with emit
        files = fetchFile;
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onloadend = function () {
            //Put the object/image in page html with scope
            $scope.content = reader.fetchFile;
        }; 
    });
});
```

Finally I show my html page where I want show the preview down the input file.

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="js/libs/angular.js/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="myController">

        <h1>Select file</h1>
        <input type="file" file-model/>
        <img ng-src="{{content}}"/>
        <div>
            <button ng-click="send()">
                send
            </button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In this way I don't obtain the preview also in this snippet there isn't the function for send the image with Json that I'll do. How can I fix the question? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert the file data that is read to Base 64 string format. Then you can use that base 64 data to show the image.

```
<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,<!-- base64 data -->' />
```

You can easily transfer this base 64 data to server since it is just a string.